# Visual Studio - AnkhSvn, TortoiseSVN, Pageant

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, pageant

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with AnkhSvn for Visual Studio work and TortoiseSVN for other legacy projects on the same machine.

I connect to the SVN server using SSH keys held in PageAnt, to prevent continual prompting for my password. This works until I need to run VS2010 as an administrator, at which point AnkhSvn prompts for my password every time I need to update/commit etc.. to the server.

Which was fine, but whenever I try to run the AnkhSvn Merge Wizard, it hangs, after the select source stage and I have to forcilbly end the VS2010 process.

I can workaround this by running PageAnt as administrator whenever running VS2010 as administrator. But this has the side effect that TortoiseSVN will prompt for my SSH password.

It seemed logical to try to run two instances of pageant, one as an administrator and one the normal way, however PageAnt will not allow two instances to run.

Has anyone a workaround so I can use TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN together, using PageAnt for authentication, regardless of whether I run VS2010 as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Windows apps can be built to not allow for duplicate processes to be run. You'll have to get the pageant team to change that.

You could run the admin instances in a virtual machine, though that may not be worth the trouble in this situation; your call.